# Pegar HTML da página e Enviar para o Controller

Tags: c#, html, jquery, ajax

Olá,

estou tentando pegar todo o html da página a partir da tag  e enviar para o meu controller, porém não estou conseguindo, segue código usado.

```
    function exportarExcel() {
    var url = '@Url.Action("ExportExcel")';
    var html = $("body").html();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {
            Html: html,
        },
    });
}
```

Função no Controller:

```
    public void ExportExcel(string Html)
    {
        Classes.Export.ToExcelHtml(Response, Html.ToString());

    }
```

Comment: é como esta sua action ?

Comment: Editei o post com a função

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O ASP.NET ignorou sua requisição por questão de segurança (XSS, *Cross-Site Scripting*). Antes do método na controller, use o atributo `ValidateInput`:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public void ExportExcel(string Html)
{
   Classes.Export.ToExcelHtml(Response, Html.ToString());       
}
```

Seu JavaScript:

```
  function exportarExcel() {
    var url = '@Url.Action("ExportExcel")';
    var html = $("body").html();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            Html: html,
        },
    });
}
```

Fontes:
[ASP.NET Request Validation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ASP.NET_Request_Validation)
[jquery - Sending HTML to Controller using Ajax POST - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37431201/8133067)